# Android combine audio and video file with ffmpeg programatically

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Like the title mentioned, I want to combine an audio file with a video file programatically on android platform. So, if your guys have any idea about it, thanks for your reply!

Comment: hi did u try with javacv/opencv?

Answer (score 0):

First, build ffmpeg for android: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android

Then you can invoke it with arguments by calling the main function in ffmpeg.c and it will be like running it normally, except it will actually run in your app's process.